# Htaccess redirect based on country of origin

Tags: htaccess, redirects, country-specific

Can a rule that filters and redirect traffic based on country of origin be implemented in .htaccess?

Can it be implemented in any other way then by an IP address? I need the solution to be as accurate as possible.

Comment: I only know of using the .htaccess but that may require a large(ish) number of rules to cover all of the IP address ranges. What countries are you interested in? That may help someone to answer your question. Push comes to shove, I can perhaps see what IP address ranges exist for any country and create an example rewrite rule(s) that you can try. I expect there may be a better way though. I have no idea how people do this other than .htaccess.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [this link (how to redirect domain according to country IP address)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9838344/how-to-redirect-domain-according-to-country-ip-address/9838434#9838434) can help you.

I think, however, that this is not a good practice.
Redirection by language or country is quite strict. It is better preferred:

- A message at the top of your site that influence the visitor to go to
  the page built with his language.
- A system that can easily change the language (flags)

This is only my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, we used to filter visitors from Nigeria by .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{ENV:IP2LOCATION_COUNTRY_SHORT} ^NG$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.google.com [L]
```

You can generate your own at http://ip2location.com/free/visitor-redirection .

Comment: You need an Apache module to use this htaccess: http://www.ip2location.com/developers/apache